# Users Denied Write Access Win 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-permissions

I recently transferred files from a Windows server 2003 (servold) to Windows server 2008 r2 (servnew)

The new server has two physical drives. User files were stored on d:\

d:\ was shared (right click on drive | sharing | advanced sharing) as "files"

**Examples of paths for staff and student directories**

d:\users\staff\mjones

d:\users\students\class_of_2020\20jsmith

**Example of the scripts that were run from the newer server (servnew) to transfer the files.**

Example domain: ab.cdef.net. I was logged in as the local admin.

md d:\users\staff\mjones

echo Y | ICACLS d:\users\staff\mjones /Grant mjones:(OI)(CI)(M,DC)

xcopy \servold\users\staff\mjones*.* d:\users\staff\mjones /s /h /v

dsmod user "cn=Mary Jones,ou=staff,dc=ab,dc=cdef,dc=net" -hmdrv x: - hmdir \srvnew\files\users\staff\mjones -email mjones@cdef.net -desc staff

1. All scripts ran without error
2. All permissions on folders, subfolders and files appear to be correct (right click on object | properties | security | select the user)
3. The Home drive is correctly mapped and gives correct access when a user logs in.

**The issues:**

1. users can log in and open their files, but they open as if they are read only. Changes can't be saved into user directories. When checking the actual files, they are not set as read only
2. Users can not save new files into their directories

**Error Message:**

\srvnew\files\users\staff\mjones\file.docx

You don't have permission to save to this location.

Contact the administrator to obtain permission.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the share?

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds more with the programs they're opening them with, especially if they are Office documents. Is "protected mode" on when they access them? This would prevent saving, open in read only, etc.